# Android retaining information across fragments

Tags: android

I have five fragments a user can switch between.  One of these fragments loads a list of users from the server to populate the UI list on the fragment.  I need the list information to persist if a user swipes to a different fragment and then swipes back to the original. I do not want the fragment to reload the users every time a user leaves the fragment and goes back.

I am looking at setRetainInsance(true) and was wondering if this is possible solution?  What would be the best way for the fragment to retain the information without being created from scratch each time.

I am using this to switch between fragements -getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.searchLayout, ratingFragment).commit();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Fragment is Just like any other object. 
 on Fragment transaction , the Fragment does not call OnCreate() method  instead it starts from onCreateView , therefore , load your users and save it an instance variable and assign it in onCreate()

Example

```
class MyFragment extends Fragment{


List<users> userList;

void onCreate(){
   userList = getUserList();}
//the list is loaded during Oncreate();
```

now imagine you have replaced the Fragment

now According to Andorid Framework , onCreate() is not Called again
instead onCreateView() is called

```
void onCreateView(){
//you can check whether instance Variable is initialised or not
if(userList != null) { 


listview.setAdapter(new Myadapter(this,userList);
```

Comment: This seems like a very good solution and the simplest of any I have seen so far.  Thank you, I will try this and let you know if it works!

Answer (score 0):

Replace the fragment by adding it to backstack.

```
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(tag);
    fragmentTransaction.replace(container, fragment, tag);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Also create object of View and return it if it's not null.

```
    private void View view ; 
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          if (view != null)
              return view;
          view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_browse_recipe, container, false);
     //initialize layout views
     return view;
    }
```